# Solving Polyester but no chromed steel

Tags: acid-base, plastics

**In short**

I'm looking for an acid that can solve a polyester, fiberglass composite. However it cannot damage steel.

First of all i like to say that i'm not a chemist. I work in a plastic moulding company. Let me sketch a background. 
We make bars out of a polyester strengthened by fiberglas. To make this we have the two materials beeing pulled through a heated steel pipe (*the mould*). The polyester melts around the fiberglass and forms a strong lightweight pole. However sometimes the pole breaks mid process and then there is a part that's stuck in the mould. Like in the picture

[image: Part stuck in mould]

It's very hard to remove the polyester/fiberglass bar from the mould, dare I say near impossible.

I was wondering if there is an acid that solves the polyester but makes no damage at all to the chrome steel mould.

Comment: Look using the terms " solvent for. ..". It seems a hard task because you have a rod trapped in the mould. If the mould cannot be open it might takes years. ..

Comment: Is it not possible to heat the mold above the melting point of the polyester, then PUSH out the stuck bar with a rod?

Comment: we tried drilling, melting, ... if there is an acid or solvent of polymer that doesn't damage the steel, i would make a system that circulates, the acid, maybe even heats it to speed up the process. If it works after weeks, i'll be happy with it, a year, or years might be a bit too long

Comment: @jeffB we tried pushing it hydraulically with a force of 800kg, hammering, and the rod is usually just too long, and has too much friction, we're talking about a mould of a length of 1m50,

Comment: Can't you pretreat the mould by coating it, say with PTFE? Or would this not help?

Comment: It's a constant cycle, there's constantly plastic and glass fibers beeing pulled through the mould, so it's not an option.

Comment: The thermal exansion of polymers is sufficiently high that if you cooled the entire thing then the polyester might break free.

Comment: Cooling to what temperature

Comment: I'd cool the whole thing to as low as possible and let it sit for a while. if that doesn't work then I would try heating the metal while the plastic is still cold.

Comment: Unless you mean cooling it below 0°C we already tried it

Comment: I repeat look for polyester solubility or even better "incompatibility" and surely you find solvents either as pure chemicals or commercial formulations. Then you can try circulating it though your system in they will be no too flammable etc...

Comment: Second to Alchimista - Google for solvents. If your polyester is PET, for example, here is a reference: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/app.1417. Also a discussion at Researchgate:https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_you_dissolve_polyethyelene_terephthalate_PET. The small available surface for contact with the plastic may mean it takes a really long time, though.